# History of Food Questions Discussion

Tags: discussion

We have a previous precedent for food history questions, which is that they are allowed: [Are questions about the history of foods and cooking off-topic?](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1921/7180), provided that the question is about food and/or cooking, and isn't otherwise a prohibited type (e.g. requests for recipes).

However, in this question: [Earliest pizza recipe?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/121323/7180) Rumtscho is calling to re-evaluate that policy in a discussion on Meta.  So here is that discussion.

Comment: I don't see any reason to change policy here, and the example question is clear enough. rumtscho, if you'd like to explain why we should tighten the rules, I'm listening, but I'd like to see something more than concern about whether we're as good at answering it as we are at easier questions. For now I'm casting the 4th reopen vote; as far as the site rules stand, it's on-topic, and we shouldn't be overriding those past decisions.

Comment: @Cascabel I was not actually calling for a discussion on the policy as a whole, I imagined a discussion on whether this one question should be closed or open. For me, it is quite clearly a case of "if the question is unsuitable anyway, being about history doesn't automatically make it stay-open-worthy". I was surprised to see how many people think otherwise, and to see what kind of answer the OP accepted. But since the meta question exists, I will take some time to gather my thoughts and write them up here, not to create new policy, but to clarify where are the boundaries of the existing one.

Comment: @rumtscho Maybe I'm reading between the lines too much here, but from what you're saying, it sounds like you're applying a _very_ high standard, and also avoiding shifts in the question that'd be consistent with what the OP is looking for and make it completely acceptable to you. The accepted answer is not surprising to me at all; it's an answer to what I understood the OP to be asking for - when/what was the first recorded recipe ("what" as in some kind of identifying information, not the contents of the recipe). I really struggle to see how that could be unacceptable.